# Django filter() lookup type documentation

Tags: python, django, filter, lookup

I looked on Django's documentation and Googled every varation of the phrase but I cannot find any documentation that exactly describes the behaviour of lookuptypes.

```
app.objects.filter(column__lookuptype=criteria)
```

I have found documentation on which lookuptypes I *can* use but not what they do or how to use them.  For example, I have no bloody clue what `__gte` does, but I cannot find good documentation on what it does either.

Is there documentation that I overlooked?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `gte` == "_Greater Than or Equal_"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are called "field lookups" in Django. Field lookups have pretty comprehensive documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4

These are pretty well documented:

- [`exact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exact)
- [`iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact)
- [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains)
- [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)
- [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)
- [`gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt)
- [`gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte)
- [`lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt)
- [`lte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte)
- [`startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#startswith)
- [`istartswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith)
- [`endswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#endswith)
- [`iendswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iendswith)
- [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)
- [`year`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year)
- [`month`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month)
- [`day`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#day)
- [`week_day`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day)
- [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)
- [`search`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search)
- [`regex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex)
- [`iregex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex)

Comment: Agh!  Okay, thank you much.  I have found this referred as lookuptype several times in some docs but just wasn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

["Field lookups" documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

Comment: Link appears to be broken.

Comment: Link is invalid